# Separate weakly connected objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I'm facing a problem that I'm sure Blender is capable of solving.
I want to individually separate weakly connected 3D objects (see an example in the picture).

I thought of the following idea:

- Remove a margin on the whole object. If this margin is big enough, it should separate the objects.
- Once the objects are separated, add the margin previously removed.

I've tried to blender with Alt+S, but it doesn't seem to do exactly that and so it doesn't separate the objects.

Do you have an idea?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: What exactly is a weakly connected object?

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't give much information on that one.
An object corresponds to two weakly connected objects if we can cut this object in two such that the missing surface of the two objects to be volumes again is less than a certain percentage of their total surface.